# OData $select not working on Web API

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use OData to return a smaller, paginated result set from my web API. I'm modifying a large, existing API so I would like to be able to do this for only this one controller and method, preferably without using the extensive 'Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData' package from NuGet, EdmModels, etc..

I've got $top and $skip working fine in my method below, but my $selects are being ignored.

My method:

```
    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.Select | System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.Top | System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.Skip )]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetByType(OrganizationType type) {
    var results = _service.List(type);
    return(Request.CreateResponse<IQueryable<OrganizationModel>>(results.Any() ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NotFound, results.AsQueryable<OrganizationModel>()));
  }
}
```

Any ideas why it's ignoring $select?

Comment: Depending how "edge" you are, it [may not be supported yet](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8b65f6f102b9e336c605f24509bb8cf2d84b9694).

Comment: what do you mean ignored? that you are getting all the properties and not just the $select'ed properties? Also, what nuget package version are you using?

Comment: What I mean is that, it will accept '$skip and $top' and return a a proper result set, but when I add in '$select', it will still send me ALL the fields, not just the selected ones. And I'm using 'Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData' 4.0.30506

Answer (score 5):

[Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData 4.0.30506](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/4.0.30506) package doesn't have the `$select` and `$expand` support. To get `$select` and `$expand` support, you have to upgrade to one of our latest packages. [5.0.0-beta2](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/5.0.0-beta2) should work. Optionally, you can try our [nightly builds](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) as well to get all the latest features.

Comment: Just install the equivalent version of WebApi and you're good to go!
For the current RC: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.0.0-rc1

Comment: My production server only has the .NET frameworks up to v4 - since this requires a newer .NET framework than 4, I'll have to wait on this for now.