# OData filter not working for my Web API (mvc 4 stack)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, iqueryable, asp.net-web-api2

This started out as a question, because I had legimate issues getting the $filter=substringof syntax to work correctly. In the process of fomatting this, I was able to fish out the detail I was overlooking.. however, I'll post this question/answer for anyone else - as I hope it serves as a useful resource.

So here's just a few of the NuGet packages I'm referencing, just to show you what version of the stack I'm on:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="4.0.30506" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

FWIW - I started with an MVC 4 application, but, had to run this NuGet command in order to end up with the first package referece shown above:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Version 4.0.30506
```

Here's my Web API controller (note: I'm *not* using entity framework.. this is just my own little business object I'm exposing as an IQueryable (notice the method decoration)

```
Public Class CustomerController
    Inherits ApiController

    Private Shared queryableListOfCustomers As IQueryable

    <Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions:=OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.All)>
    Public Function GetList(opts As OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions) As IQueryable(Of CodeBase)
         /*
         here is where I would insert singleton logic to populate the Shared queryableListOfCustomers member 
         */
          If opts IsNot Nothing Then
            Return opts.ApplyTo(queryableListOfCustomers)
          End If

        Return queryableListOfCustomers
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's an example URL string, where users type into an auto-suggest field their search parameter. In this case, I have begun to type a customer name (first letter I typed was a 'g') so I want to return all customers that may have the current input anywhere in the customer name:

```
 localhost:27746/api/Customer/List?shiptypecode=AW&$filter=substringof('g',DisplayLabel) eq true&$top=40&$select=Code,DisplayLabel&$inlinecount=allpages
```

EDIT:
and here's the case-insensitive search URL:

```
 localhost:27746/api/Customer/List?shiptypecode=AW&$filter=substringof(tolower('g'),tolower(DisplayLabel)) eq true&$top=40
```

Comment: First dumb mistake I made: the jquery widget I was using to do my auto-suggest logic, had poorly written URL formatting and I had two question marks in my URL.. where one of those should have been an ampersand

Comment: Second mistake that I kept making: for the substringof function, the thing your searching for comes first, and then the property name. So, I had to swap my parameters around. And, I didn't have the " eq true" tacked onto the end like I needed.

Comment: I've just discovered that my $select is not working, and it [never will until I upgrade my .NET framework on my production server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617946/odata-select-not-working-on-web-api)

Comment: And if you want case-insenstive searching, [we need to use tolower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495905/odata-query-filter-conditions-and-case-sensitivity)